# How to configure one way One-to-One relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public Guid CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}  

public class Currency
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`Currency` is used by many table, for example `BankAccount` and `PurhasePayment`. So I've done this in my `EntityTypeBuilder<BankAccount> builder`

```
builder.HasOne(c => c.Currency)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<BankAccount>(e => e.CurrencyId);
```

However, when I checked the database. It's creating a unique

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_bank_account_currency_id ON public.bank_account USING btree (currency_id);`

which is causing duplicate error when more than one records using the same `Currency` for example USD.

What's the correct FluentAPI syntax? I'm using EF Core 6. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me, to be a one-to-many relationship (one currency is used in many bank accounts).

Comment: @Oliver: Thanks, I always thought WithMany is referring to Parent/Child Collection relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.HasOne(c => c.Currency)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CurrencyId);
```